# Ag grid header checkbox selection

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using `Ag-grid` with server-side data

HTML code is:

```html
<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="isShowProceedButton" #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 70vh; float: left;" class="ag-theme-balham template-grid" [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" rowSelection="multiple">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

TS file code:

```js
this.columnDefs.push({
  // headerName: keyValues[j], field: this.headers[i],
  headerName: keyValues[j],
  field: this.headers[i],
  'isMapped': 0,
  'skipRow': this.rowHeader[i].skipRow,
  headerComponentFramework: AgGridCheckboxComponent,
  'isShowCheckBox': this.isShowProceedButton
})
```

It will show me the grid with checkbox:

[image]

Why when I uncheck the checkbox e.g. uncheck FY2014E and scroll horizontally then again it shows the checkbox as selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Harshal you have to set suppressColumnVirtualisation property in your gridOptions like that:

```
this.gridOptions.suppressColumnVirtualisation = true;
```